# drupal 8 entity updated entity_keys in backoffice

Tags: entity, drupal-8

In drupal 8, I create a new entity type with `command drupal generate:entity`.

I have a script who generate content entity. It's works.

I can change all information (my fields) in backoffice.
But I can't edit the option information (entity_keys): autor, status and date of updated.

How I can show in the backoffice Edit entity the "Option Information" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
In the class (namespace Drupal\flora\Entity) of my entity, there is a function baseFieldDefinitions. In this function you can specify which fields to display in the backoffice.